# Highcharts customEvents plugin + Highstock Error

Tags: javascript, highcharts, custom-events

I am currently trying use customEvents plugin with my Highstock lib.

http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events

However, after importing customEvents.js, I got the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'plotLines' of undefined at HC.Chart.customEvent.HC.Chart.customEvent.resetAxisEvents
```

On the website, it says that it has dependencies of highcharts v3.0.7. Since the highstock lib version is different that the version of highcharts. Currently, I am using the latest version of highstock lib v2.1.8

Is there anyone familiar with this issue?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have already fixed this issue in that commit: https://github.com/blacklabel/custom_events/issues/28

Let me know if problem still appears.